# Strategy for intercommunication across multiple deployed environments in Azure

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

I am looking for best practice of intercommunication across multiple roles in Azure in multiple deployment environments.

We have the following deployment environments

1. Developers local deployment
2. Share development deployment in azure
3. QA deployment in azure
4. Pre production deployment
5. Production deployment
6. etc..

In all those deployments we have multiple web roles as well worker roles.

I am looking for best practice to create a unique identifier for each deployment so we can do intercommunication across the roles for each deployment.

If for example i am using the azure Queue or Service bus how could i uniquely identify each deployment so the messages does not cross from one environment to the other?

Thanks,
Noam

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to look into a global static variable called RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId available from Azure Service Runtime.

This variable will be unique for every deployed Azure service (note, not Role).

Caveats:

1) if you need a unique number per each Role, append a RoleName to this variable: RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name

2) deployments in local dev mode follow a different naming convention and do not return a Guid for the deployment id. Might want to implement a Guid generation strategy for them.

Answer (score 0):

A better option, that we use across our Dev, Test & Prod environments - is to simply create Dev, Test & Prod storage containers and service buses.  We use the service config definitions for each build environment to control which container/bus is in use.  This is especially important if you are using diagnostics, you really should be using a separate container for diagnostics as well.

Answer (score 0):

You would likely want to group the set of services into a single Cloud Service (or probably a VNet), and then just use WCF (net.tcp) communications internally.

Example here: http://tk.azurewebsites.net/2013/03/06/burst-up-to-the-cloud-with-a-preconfigured-ip-address-and-vpn/

[image]

Ignore the "VPN" part of the picture - that has to do with some specific stuff I was mentioning in the article.